# Schengen area violation database

Tags: schengen, switzerland, visa-bans

Where do I find Schengen Area records of violation and punishment for a 90 day stay violation and fine in Switzerland in June 2019 ?  The fine was paid. I never received any other communication.  How do I know if any ban exists ?

Comment: You would have to write to the office where you paid the fine and ask. There won't be a 'violation database' as such. A ban is unlikly, since you would have recieved a letter informing you of that.

Comment: @MarkJohnson it should be noted in the SIS no? That's what this system is for

Answer (score 3):

A record of this violation should be accessible in the Schengen Information System (SIS II). This system is maintained by each member state and you can request your information from the respective member state:

*[Switzerland](https://www.edoeb.admin.ch/edoeb/en/home/data-protection/police--defence-and-migration/the-schengen-agreement-and-the-dublin-regulation/the-schengen-information-system--sis--and-your-personal-data.html) is on Page 87 of the pdf titled "Guide for exercising the right of access to the Schengen Information System (SIS II)" guide on the Federal Data Protection and Information Commission website.*

It points you to exactly which authority you must direct your request.